Next.js Static Exports html file not found
i choose "Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) ... No"
I have added output: 'export' to next.config.js
and run build, there was some css/js present in the out/ directory, but no html was found, I didn't modify anything, just a newly installed next.js
Where is this html hiding? Thanks.
I can see the html file if i choose "App Router - YES", whats the reason?
